# Can you initialise a pointer and the corresponding object in one line in c++?

Tags: c++

```
class test {
    public:
    int& n;
    test(int& n) : n(n) {}
};

int main() {
    test* ptr = ptr(3); // something like this and 3 
 // should be a variable as pointed out in the comments
}
```

Can you initialise a pointer and the object that it points to in one line?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to achieve, the correct answer depends on the intended storage duration for the pointed instance.

Comment: Yes, by using `new` to create the object dynamically. Which is something any decent book, tutorial or class should have taught you.

Comment: `ptr(3)` is an error here. If you are using Visual Studio, it uses an extension by default which will allow this code to compile. But it still contains an error. You can't bind a `int&` to a literal. You should use `int` here instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I started  learning c++ 2 days ago and haven't considered any book yet, sorry

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thanks that you're always so actively answering!

Comment: You can get a good C++ book [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Please do that, it's quite important for learning. Or take classes. Online-tutorials can only take you a bit of the way anyway. And anyway, if you're already working on pointers after only two days then you're probably taking it a little too fast, I recommend that you slow down and learn the basics (from a book) first. Pointers is an *advanced* topic.

Comment: Trust me you want a good book. C++ is an exacting language does not treat coding by trial and error particularly well. Worse, if you try looking up stuff online you'll find that the bulk of advice given is poor-to-outright-harmful. You won't be able to tell what's good advice from what's bad until you know enough of the C++ fundamentals to know what good code should look ([and smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)) like.

Comment: (If your are beginner,) don't try to have one liner code (as code-golf), but understandable correct code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
class test {
    public:
    int& n;
    test(int& n) : n(n) {}
};

int main() {
    int value = 3;
    test obj(value), *ptr = &obj;
}
```

Note that `int& n` cannot accept literal like `3`.

Another choice is using `new` to create an object on the heap.

```
class test {
    public:
    int& n;
    test(int& n) : n(n) {}
};

int main() {
    int value = 3;
    test *ptr = new test(value); // create an object
    delete ptr; // delete the object
}
```

Comment: I feel this answer would be improved by more clearly indicating the difference between the two alternatives. Currently, to a beginner, it may appear as if the answer is providing two equivalent solutions. In reality, only one is appropriate for any given use case.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm familiar with the concepts of memory and know how these answers differ, but in general I agree.

Comment: @HerkulesOl • the abstract C++ machine has the concept of *automatic storage* and *dynamic storage* (and [a few others](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) not used in MikeCat’s examples). Are those the “concepts of memory” to which you are referring?